# Django db.connection.cursor.fetchone() returns emty result, when raw SQL doesn't

Tags: python, sql, django, mysql-python

I have method in a cusom QuerySet that performs raw SQL query to database.

```
class QuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def get_short(self, language_code='en'):
        """Returns shortest name for given language"""
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''SELECT t.name FROM translation t, name n
                            WHERE n.id IN (%s)
                            AND t.link_id = n.id
                            AND t.lang_id = %s
                            ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(t.name)
                            LIMIT 1''', [','.join(["'%s'" % obj.pk for obj in self]), get_language(language_code).pk])
        name = cursor.fetchone()
        if name:
            return name[0]
```

But it returns empty result. `cursor.fetchone()` return `None` instead of value. When I execute raw SQL on the same database:

```
SELECT t.name FROM translation t, name n
                              WHERE n.id IN ('166','167')
                              AND t.link_id = n.id
                              AND t.lang_id = 40
                              ORDER BY  CHAR_LENGTH(t.name)
                              LIMIT 1
```

It returns properly value.

Where I wrong? Please, help!

Comment: I'd let django print the exact sql statement before executing it, so that you can compare it to your explicit statement.

Comment: SQL statement from django logs is exactly similiar to that I explained in post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without the `", ".join` to format your first parameter.

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT t.name FROM translation t, name n
                            WHERE n.id IN %s
                            AND t.link_id = n.id
                            AND t.lang_id = %s
                            ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(t.name)
                            LIMIT 1''', [tuple(obj.pk for obj in self), get_language(language_code).pk])
```